# Cannot attach the file '<>.mdf' as database '<>'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm working on a project with different implementations of DbContext. Using EF code first, I generate migration :

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName <> -Force
Add-Migration <>_DB_v1.0
Update-Database -Verbose
```

The update always tries to attach the *.mdf file but no file is ever genrated in local, and I'm working on a distant SQL Server (Distant virtual DB)
the `Update-Script` option successfully generates the SQL file and well executed on the Db, but I always get error to execute last update before going on new migration.

Could any body help ?

Project is in .net 4.6, and using EF 6.0.

Sorry not able to paste code for confidentiality. I may ensure that All connection string, project conf. and so are perfectly set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error reason: 
1- Indicate explicitly the providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" in the connectionStrings definition

2- Executing the migration, specify the -ConnectionStringName, even if the name displaed in the console seems to be OK.

Add-Migration DB_vX.x -ConnectionStringName XXX_Database
update-database -Verbose -Script -ConnectionStringName XXX_Database

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that migration history table in the Db and Migrations files in your Solution are match.

I think you miss some migration.